# Can I change the address hyperlinks navigate to, programatically?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, team-foundation-server

We used to have a TFS server hosted locally on let's say `HTTP://tfs.corp.olddomain.com/tfs/`. There are hundreds of e-mails in my inbox with a link to a work item under that URL, e.g. `HTTP://tfs.corp.olddomain.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/_workitems/edit/12345`

We recently changed the server over to a new domain, so the base address is now `HTTP://tfs.corp.newdomain.com/`

For any given link in my inbox that looks for `HTTP://tfs.corp.olddomain.com/tfs/`, the page doesn't exist so I end up with

> This site can’t be reached

Can I force Outlook to change the path to `HTTP://tfs.corp.newdomain.com/`, and append the remainder of the URL?

**Edit:** The new URL doesn't have the `/tfs/` section in the path.

Comment: If you can add the old domain to your website, even if the domain itself doesn't exist, you can alter your hostname so the old domain points to the same server and it should then work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can have the *browser* do it instead.

For major browsers (Firefox, Chrome) there are plenty of "URL rewriter" extensions, some only changing fixed prefixes, others supporting regex-based rewrite.

---

It may also be possible to edit the actual message content (at least for IMAP-capable servers) – in the worst case you could use Outlook to download all the messages into plain-text .eml files (not the Outlook binary .msg!), mass-edit them, then drag & drop back to your Outlook inbox.

Comment: I went for this option, using a Chrome extension. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to map `tfs.corp.olddomain.com` to the IP address
of `tfs.corp.newdomain.com`.

If the IP address of `tfs.corp.newdomain.com` is `123.456.789.012`, then add
the following line to the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
123.456.789.012   tfs.corp.olddomain.com
```

A more complicated solution would be to write a VBA macro that will massage an
email into shape before its display, but that solution is much more difficult.

Comment: thanks. I ended up going down the URL re-write route, as it's easier for other people to follow and doesn't require elevated privileges.